# celery giving Rate limit attempt for unknown task task name

Tags: celery

basically i am running two workers on celery, different module and different queue but same rabbitmq

```
celery worker -l info -A module_name.main.tasks -Q queue_one

celery worker -l info -A module_name.sub.sub_task -Q queue_two
```

when i try to rate limit 1st task present on 1 module i get this error from 2nd worker running the the other module..

```
app.control.rate_limit('module_name.main.tasks.method', '30/m')
```

Rate limit attempt for unknown task

I would prefer if the rate limit call would go to the worker that is working on that module and not to the other workers which are not working on that module.

any idea how to resolve this ??

Update: adding code:

```
celery_worker_base.py:

from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('poc',
             backend='mongodb://user:pass@ip:27017/collection',
             broker='amqp://user:pass@ip/vhost',
             include=['poc.main.proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
    CELERY_ROUTES = {'poc.main.proj.tasks': {'queue': 'proj_tasks'}}
)

app.control.rate_limit('poc.main.proj.tasks.get', '30/m')
app.control.rate_limit('poc.main.proj.tasks.compute', '30/m')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

celery worker code: tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from poc.celery.celery_worker_base import app

@app.task
def get(url):
    print "calling get"

@app.task
def compute(info):
    print "calling compute"
```

Another module: celery_master.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from poc.config.config import *

from boto import ec2

master_app = Celery('poc',
             backend='mongodb://user:pass@ip:27017/collection',
             broker='amqp://user:pass@ip/vhost',
             include=['poc.main.proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
master_app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'instance-check-every-fifteen-minute': {
            'task': 'poc.main.instance.check.check_count',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=900),
            'options': {'queue' : 'instance_check'}
        }
    },
    CELERY_ROUTES = {'poc.main.instance.check': {'queue': 'instance_check'}},
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
)

region = ec2.connect_to_region(
    REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master_app.start()
```

master worker: check.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from poc.config.config import *
from poc.celery.celery_master import master_app, region

@master_app.task
def check_count():
    print "calling check"
```

PS: thanks for not down-voting the question.

Comment: can you post  your code? i am able to run two different tasks by different workers at different rate limits with 2 queues without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding celery not being able to find the task, I would ensure you are passing them according to how they are listed by `app.control.app.tasks`.

This provides a dict of known tasks, where the keys are what are eligible for passing to `control.rate_limit()`.